From quenched to annealed limit theorems
Consider a discrete time process $X = (X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ in a random environment. If I can show that for every realisation of the random environment (i.e. under the quenched measure $P^{\omega}$) I have that $X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor} / \sqrt{n}$ converges to a Brownian motion $W_t$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then can I conclude that $X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor} / \sqrt{n}$ also converges to a Brownian motion as $n \rightarrow \infty$ under the annealed measure $\mathbb{P}$?
Update:
I think this should be true as I have that for $\mathbb{P}$ almost any environment
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^{\omega}\left(\left(\frac{X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right) = P\left((W_t)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right).$$
Now since $P^{\omega}\left(\left(\frac{X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right) \leq 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\left(\frac{X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right) &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[P^{\omega}\left(\left(\frac{X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right) \right] \\[1em]
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P^{\omega}\left(\left(\frac{X_{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right) \right] \\[1em]
&= P\left((W_t)_{t \in [0,T]} \in \mathcal{I}\right).
\end{align}
$$
Is it correct to argue that in J1 topology?
